# changing directory with BASH script not working

Tags: python, unix, batch-file, directory

I have a script file ("testing" w/ no filename) that contains:

```
cd /userdata/waf/Template
iaprod -python myscript.py>Outputlog
echo "hello"
```

When I go into the command window, I type the following and get this output:

```
-bash-3.00$ chmod 775 testing
-bash-3.00$ ./testing
: No such file or directorydata/acct/waf/Template
<<Starting on sim1>>
hello
```

So for some reason, the change directory command in the first line isn't working. The python script and echo in the last two lines, however, are working fine. Only problem is that I need to run the python script in the right directory.

Any ideas why cd isn't working out of all things? If I type the code  directly  into the command line verbatim, everything works fine.

Comment: Your on what operating system and how are you executing the script? If it is a Makefile, the directory won't persist unless you use parentheses to group the command.

Answer (score 1):

Check for a stray carriage return character (ASCII code point 13) at the end of the `cd` command line. The garbled error message suggests that one is present.

Lines in shell scripts (and just about everything else except text in Internet protocols) must end with ASCII LF (code point 10), not CR+LF.

Comment: Hmm well I tried using dos2unix on the script file and it's still giving me the same error. Is there another way you can recommend to fix this?

Comment: Can you produce a hex dump (`od -tx1` or similar) of your script? The line should end with 74 65 0a (ASCII: "t" "e" NL). I say this because an error message where `: No such file or directory` has overwritten the beginning of the line it appears on really looks like a stray CR.